# setup of local bind9 with forwarders is not working

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

my idea:
I have a bind9 installation hosting a domain with a zone file.
The same domain is also hosted at an dns provider, but all entries are either or.
So the external dns e.g. hosts dns for [www.xxxxx.xx](http://www.xxxxx.xx) where the internal dns only hosts entries for clients and so on.

Now there was the idea to setup the bind9 instance with forwarders (forward first) to look at the external dns for all queries first and if not found search the internal zone file.

I have tried, but with no success.

my named.conf.options:

```
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
                9.9.9.9;                // Malware-Blockierung, DNSSEC-Validierung
                1.1.1.1;                // Cloudflare und APNIC (1.1.1.1) (Empfohlen)
                8.8.8.8;                // google-public-dns-a.google.com (Empfohlen)
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        listen-on { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-query-cache { any; };
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { any; };
};
```

my named.conf.local

```
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
include "/etc/bind/blacklisted.domains";

zone "averlon.de" {
        type primary;
        file "/etc/bind/pri.averlon.de";
        forwarders {
                109.201.133.111;
        };
        forward first;
};
```

my pri.averlon.de

```
$TTL    86400
$ORIGIN averlon.de. ; base domain-name

@       IN      SOA       ns.averlon.de. avadmin.averlon.de. (
                          2022071703      ; Serial
                          10800   ; Refresh
                          3600    ; Retry
                          604800  ; Expire
                          10800 ) ; Minimum

@               IN NS           ns.averlon.de.
@               IN MX           10 smtp.averlon.de.
@               IN A            192.168.108.2           
localhost       IN A            127.0.0.1
ns              IN A            192.168.110.8
mail            IN A            179.254.4.101           
smtp            IN A            192.168.110.8           
shop            IN A            192.168.108.2                
sh              IN A            192.168.108.2                
f42252ro        IN A            192.168.108.1
```

Now. If I run a dig command on the host running bind9 I get:

```
dig @localhost www.averlon.de +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @localhost www.averlon.de +trace
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
.                       513393  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       513393  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20220730050000 20220717040000 20826 . J8JBdTFZie6wbXDkJ2rdnuXGknlJKXMsMjAyZIJyzJN7FOKtFESBPuAH 6llcLbi9qd4u5mvQPL7ZevtAfmG6QLNhT5WrQ6aIqmcVkuG2rqfJTGKx Gob9+k8QK219jrrSxIutNpzxLMUW82kU7AZGjoorTWd6zQRVmnJ096HI HT/V6Dg1wvq0vlFv9N054lztadGomqdwe2e0f9RScOkgZuo/LnNSaMr6 bELAVk6J/55ESP7/3DgfcT6lC6NR5wQ94PqZrLDRNg/TTSao2KxIoowh jrQhRCt99/eF+eQuQe3nm+XS2RHHQooF/86yXFTMwg1PfH3KbynBpdu8 S5WBeg==
;; Received 1137 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(localhost) in 4 ms

de.                     172800  IN      NS      a.nic.de.
de.                     172800  IN      NS      f.nic.de.
de.                     172800  IN      NS      l.de.net.
de.                     172800  IN      NS      n.de.net.
de.                     172800  IN      NS      s.de.net.
de.                     172800  IN      NS      z.nic.de.
de.                     86400   IN      DS      26755 8 2 F341357809A5954311CCB82ADE114C6C1D724A75C0395137AA397803 5425E78D
de.                     86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20220730050000 20220717040000 20826 . WGYLyUErNb+VbHB0kONhQq8/1oSZAVnXZtYDaFK/+M4hnT8p/UnMlJeX HbjBfi2PctrbABg5ziKglItg9rD7Gb4apgD6E85rGarfAuwu1lo0uQIM 8RIqZE5ivdHTpsxKz8mzo2IvCKhG9U9KPVGvHY9DtauXBvGTXlv9u/L+ chxBUDiIhG0cRaKvV0xsf3ATCs/uYlvCg3IarJ0b/fZNitP1JgxuSvzZ 7HKyYKBu2LOBr2noO+lzU6dRG0uyXVlr2f5fnGQBRLdZVMqoq+OlaXTK UC69/x/nslu6waE+tD/NQ7cTj1TYpt8dyfcBTh2oVEUL+CdtlRRzadoQ xricXA==
;; Received 748 bytes from 199.7.91.13#53(d.root-servers.net) in 16 ms

averlon.de.             86400   IN      NS      ns32.cloudns.net.
averlon.de.             86400   IN      NS      ns33.cloudns.net.
averlon.de.             86400   IN      NS      ns34.cloudns.net.
averlon.de.             86400   IN      NS      ns31.cloudns.net.
tjlb7qbojvmlf1s6gdriru7vsms1lg16.de. 7200 IN NSEC3 1 1 15 CA12B74ADB90591A TJLFJPRVCMSTH243PMI98VQTJ9PGI7US NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
tjlb7qbojvmlf1s6gdriru7vsms1lg16.de. 7200 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 7200 20220731050950 20220717033950 28005 de. p0zXnYn47f120Af5Fl4pjk/Hvx5LFmswEdH6nKYGD+TFdPo3H6pwZjZ9 KlD9J+VUj0dxGaim4TUFSdUSkZltsH+3LtVMnyFjMwRfhfebfhnRJUVK aBFTLShxr3uJIMRy3FY07CgIR4xDCSxqjXorpaX2+uswzGcvMLUNATrK T6w=
jab68vfs0v3ne86s58ormns0s5vhag6h.de. 7200 IN NSEC3 1 1 15 CA12B74ADB90591A JABAFFHE0Q32G4KRIHQDV489VPJ0QMJI A RRSIG
jab68vfs0v3ne86s58ormns0s5vhag6h.de. 7200 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 7200 20220731060957 20220717043957 28005 de. AYrNlmMl5tdvtjr3nmctdRG88SuV4zRyuuf0mE0PtF/kJILmkyUZ4BYQ Z8Zc3ViDWp2Al2CVb6Apn9EoQOtjPx1lUGGxoPjd2X0ppmj2wc47iZDJ D75mAgkYSNEvERYQafK4tj/CQ6bRexY1MKt44Y4fFRfskKs/0TpYZ8nN lV0=
;; Received 659 bytes from 194.0.0.53#53(a.nic.de) in 28 ms

www.averlon.de.         3600    IN      A       87.170.18.18
averlon.de.             3600    IN      NS      ns32.cloudns.net.
averlon.de.             3600    IN      NS      ns34.cloudns.net.
averlon.de.             3600    IN      NS      ns31.cloudns.net.
averlon.de.             3600    IN      NS      ns33.cloudns.net.
;; Received 146 bytes from 109.201.133.111#53(ns31.cloudns.net) in 24 ms
```

This looks to me as if the correct dns entry **87.170.18.18** on the external dns is found.

But when I do:

```
host www.averlon.de
Host www.averlon.de not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Any idea what could be wrong to fetch the correct ip address from the external dns is appreciated.

Regards
Kallewirsch

Comment: `www.averlon.de. 3553  IN  A   84.190.101.52` check your `resolve.conf` if a specific dns server is set. if you wanna use it for your network as a domain name you need to ensure to use a sub domain

Comment: Your problem starts with: "my idea: I have a bind9 installation hosting a domain with a zone file. The same domain is also hosted at an dns provider," as this is absolutely not how the DNS is supposed to work. Try "forward first" statement, but more generally, you may be better to stop running the zone locally, to use views optionnally at the provider if available, or use the RPZ feature locally with a recursive nameserver you control. Mixing recursive and authoritative featurs in a single running DNS instance is not a good idea. Also not sure if your question is really in a business setting..

Comment: @PatrickMevzek
if you mean business in the sense of money: no. But it is some alarm system for your town if base water rises. So - yes.

Anyhow:
I expected the "forward" statement to work as documented - or as I understand the documentation:
"A value of first is the default and causes the server to query the forwarders first; if that does not answer the question, the server then looks for the answer itself."
So I expected to bind9 forward the query first to the servers listed in forwarders and if no result is return look into his own zone file.

mmh - seems I am wrong.

Comment: "So I expected to bind9 forward the query first to the servers listed in forwarders and if no result is return look into his own zone file. mmh - seems I am wrong. " Yes this is NOT how things are supposed to work. You are mixing authoritative and recursive services, you will get only problems with that. See previous comment with other ideas, and look at other software like `dnsmasq` that are simpler and may be good enough for your needs. Or `dnsdist` for a bigger swiss knife tool. As for business or not, please read https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic